# Dodge not working in ggplot geom_col

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am going crazy with this, I know I am just doing something simple wrong.

All I want to do is to get this simple plot to go side by side to evaluate paired data.  position = "dodge is not working

```
require(tidyverse)
mine = tibble(
x = seq(1,36,1)
y = rnorm(36),
z = rexp(36)
)

ggplot(data = mine,aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_col(colour = "red") + 
  geom_col(aes(x,z),colour="white")
```

I am either putting it in the wrong place, or my data is not set up correctly, but this should be simple!!

Answer (score 5):

You need to prepare the data in a tidy way. Then you can use fill to separate the variables:

```
require(tidyr)
dp <- gather(mine, Var,Value,-x)


ggplot(data = dp,aes(x,Value, fill=Var)) + 
  geom_col( position="dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red","white"))
```